# Is it better to have > 2 redis processes on an 4 core VM OR 1 redis process on a VM with 2 cores?

Tags: redis

The current redis setup we have is a single redis process on a 4 core VM on a cloud provider (eg. AWS / GCP), bare metal isn't possible. This redis runs in a cluster mode and thus we have > 10 VMs in this cluster. The CPU utilization in these VMs never goes above 25% including other processes to support redis (tools to push metrics and logs etc..). I know that redis event loop is single threaded and IO operations utilise the other cores therefore the CPU utilization not being high is expected.

Given the above points I went about researching the right way to have this setup. I stumbled upon a blog by redis which recommended to have a [8 core machine](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/administering/designing-production/hardware-requirements/) and multiple redis processes in it. This recommendation is for Redis Enterprise Server and I don't know if it applies to Redis Cluster as well, not sure if they are the same either.

I am considering the approach of using 8 core machine and multiple processes in it, would this be the correct approach for a redis cluster?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what your concerns are, what your aims are, what your workload is like, nor how you define *"better"*.

Comment: @MarkSetchell would I face any issues if I run a redis cluster with 3 masters and 3 replica per master node in separate VMs with 2 cores, that is a total of 15 node cluster? By issue I mean that would the cluster have any availability issues.